# Show recently used files in Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome like in Unity

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, activities-overview, gnome-dash

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity for a while before switching to Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3.28.2. But Gnome dash doesn't show recently used files as Unity dash does.

I have had a look through some extensions like Journal, Jump Lists, Recent Items but they are either too old or using dropdown list.

So, How can I get the gnome dash to display recently used files?

Comment: You can't get the same. What's available for files  is `Recent`  in nautilus sidebar and `Frequently used` in gnome shell's  `Show Applications`

Comment: That sad :(. Thank you.